# Warning message running Play 2.5.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

Whenever I run my application with `activator run` I get the following warning:

```
"The system cannot find the file BIN_DIRECTORY\..\conf\sbtconfig.txt"
```

What does this message mean? Should I create this file? The application works fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@ps0604 Firstly, you should follow James Higgins-Thomas's 2nd answer and edit the C:\your\path\to\activator-dist-1.3.10\bin\activator.bat file and add a closing % symbol

```
set SBT_HOME=%BIN_DIRECTORY%
```

Secondly, the sbtconfig.txt found in the Scala directory C:\Program Files\sbt\conf\ needs to be copied to C:\your\path\to\activator-dist-1.3.10\conf. The google posting is from 2013 - so I think it's a bit dated

Mind you, I think that it's odd that the SBT_HOME variable would point to a directory in Activator. It might be better to have

```
set SBT_HOME="c:\Program Files\sbt\"
```

(I know it's hard coded - not the best)

And then fix

```
set FN="%SBT_HOME%\conf\sbtconfig.txt"
```

Comment: I don't have the directory `C:\Program Files\sbt\conf\ ` should I install sbt? I don't need to install sbt to run play

Comment: Yes! Surprisingly, Activator's install instructions say nothing about SBT.

http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html

Comment: And I assume that installing sbt will not break the Play installation

Comment: Just to let you know, This is the limit of my knowledge of Play, SBT and Scala. I've stopped exploring installing Play. My manager has given me other work to do. 

Best of Luck.

Comment: I had an additional problem. Activator was in a directory like `program files...`, so I needed to change the bat file to deal with the space in the directory name. The updated line I changed was `for %%d in ("%BIN_DIRECTORY%") do set ACTIVATOR_HOME=%%~dpd` - I inserted the quotation marks either side of `%BIN_DIRECTORY%`.

Comment: What worked for me was - in addition to this answer - to remove the two dots before `conf` in `set FN=%SBT_HOME%\conf\sbtconfig.txt`

Comment: I got the same message, but the application COULDN'T start (instead of works fine as described in this question). The reason was that my JAVA_HOME path contains "whitespace". Just change the JAVA_HOME directory location which contains no whitepsace

Comment: Always avoid directories with white space. "Program Files"  has caused more problems than I care to remember.

Comment: All changes are done in `sbt.bat` and `activator.bat` jut to point to the correct SBT_HOME. For example in activator.bat:`set FN=%SBT_HOME%conf\sbtconfig.txt`.

Comment: The ending % sign for SBT_HOME has been fixed, finally!

Answer (score 1):

Fix **activator.bat**

In addition to fixing the missing % after %BIN_DIRECTORY

```
set SBT_HOME=%BIN_DIRECTORY%
```

I also had to add quotes arround it in

```
for %%D in ("%BIN_DIRECTORY%") do
```

I put all my java in Program Files which contains a space.....
The old drama still around every now an then....

But now it starts :)

```
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /127.0.0.1:8888
[info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
```

Answer (score 1):

@Haim Raman. Or you could just leave the 
`set SBT_HOME=%BIN_DIRECTORY%` 
and rather define your **sbtconfig.txt** file location in the same activator.bat file.

i.e. *pathToactivatorfolder/bin/activator.bat*

So let's say if your activator is installed in ***"C:\activator"*** you do that by changing the line:
`set FN=%SBT_HOME%..\conf\sbtconfig.txt.`

To :
`set FN=%SBT_HOME%\..\..\pathTosbtfolder\conf\sbtconfig.txt`

So let's say if your sbt is installed in ***"C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt"*** (remember activator is installed in  ***"C:\activator"***)
 
then your settings will look like this:
`set FN=%SBT_HOME%\..\..\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf\sbtconfig.txt`

**Note that \..\..\ just means going up two directories.** So you can always define your sbtconfig.txt location relative to your activator install path.