# Play framework build dist file, or any old commands (clean compile stage) with activator 1.3.10 for windows

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, playframework, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to update my activator launcher for my play framework app from older versions to latest one, I was using versions from 1.3.6 to 1.3.8 without any issues with running commands like the following:

```
ACTIVATOR_BIN_PATH> activator clean compile stage dist
```

But I tried to use the latest version 1.3.10 its not working, its says something like:

```
ACTIVATOR_HOME=[PROJECT_PATH]\play-java
The system cannot find the file [PROJECT_PATH]\play-java\bin\..\conf\sbtconfig.txt.
 Did not detect an activator project in this directory.
 - activator
 Load an existing project (has to be executed from the project directory)
 or print this help message if no project is found

 Sub-commands
 - activator ui
 Open the project in the UI if executed from an existing project
 directory, otherwise open a project-creation UI.

 - activator new [project-name] [template-name]
 Create a new project, prompting for project-name if missing and helping you
 find a template if template-name is not provided.

 - activator list-templates
 Fetch the latest template list and print it to the console.
```

You can donwload activators ([1.3.8-minimal](https://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.8/typesafe-activator-1.3.8-minimal.zip)) and ([1.3.10-minimal](https://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.10/typesafe-activator-1.3.10-minimal.zip)), for 1.3.10 donwnload ([scala-sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html)) and then, apply fixes provided here : [Warning message running Play 2.5.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879205/warning-message-running-play-2-5-2)

Then you can start first project for both activators:

```
activator new my-first-app play-java
```

My plugin.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mmizutani" % "sbt-play-gulp" % "0.1.1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I found some kind of solution for it, moved the activator from `bin` folder one step back to [PROJECT_PATH] , and changes some lines

changes valued for `BIN_DIRECTORY`and `ACTIVATOR_HOME` from:

```
set BIN_DIRECTORY=%~dp0
set BIN_DIRECTORY=%BIN_DIRECTORY:~0,-1%
for %%d in (%BIN_DIRECTORY%) do set ACTIVATOR_HOME=%%~dpd
set ACTIVATOR_HOME=%ACTIVATOR_HOME:~0,-1%
```

to:

```
set BIN_DIRECTORY=%~dp0
set BIN_DIRECTORY=%BIN_DIRECTORY:~0,-1%
for %%d in (%BIN_DIRECTORY%) do set ACTIVATOR_HOME=%~dp0
set ACTIVATOR_HOME=%ACTIVATOR_HOME:~0,-1%
```

and `SBT_HOME` to :

```
set SBT_HOME=%BIN_DIRECTORY%
```

and `FN` to :

```
set FN=%SBT_HOME%\conf\sbtconfig.txt
```

For Linux version (bash), changed `sbt_home` to this:

```
declare -r sbt_home="$(realpath "$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")")"
```

And seems now its working.

Not really sure if there is a way to fix it without move the activator out of bin, since Linux version seems still working well inside bin, but the windows does not.

But this solution works for now anyway.