# Server access Error: Connection timed out

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework. I am building an app using play 2.3 version. For this I have downloaded activator. After downloading activator I have created one of the project using command activator new.
For Demo I have created the project `testjava` under directory `C:\Users\kamal.c.sharma`.
Now when I am trying to run this project from cmd through this command 
`C:\Users\kamal.c.sharma\testjava>activator` run on command prompt its showing the following error --

```
ACTIVATOR_HOME=C:\Program Files\activator-dist-1.3.12
The system cannot find the file C:\Program Files\activator-dist-1.3.12\bin\..\conf\sbtconfig.txt.
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\kamal.c.sharma\testjava\project
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/kamal.c.sharma/testjava/project/}testjava-build...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.5.10 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.10/ivys/ivy.xml
...
```

Please guys help me out.I have tried a lot of thing but nothing works out

Comment: Look here https://playframework.com/download#activator

Comment: Did you try this answer? looks very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879205/warning-message-running-play-2-5-x